# How can I extract a single update out of WSUS for an unmanaged PC?

Tags: windows-update, wsus

We use Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) on our LAN to download and distribute updates from Microsoft.

I have an unmanaged computer that needs Vista Service Pack 2. Instead of downloading the file, which could be up to 350 MB, can I just pull it out of WSUS?

I know it’s in the server’s D:\WSUS directory somewhere—but where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe in the WSUS console if you look at the properties of an update the "File URI" contains the physical path to the location or at least the name of the file so you can search for it in the cache.

Comment: +1 True, this would be my preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

The updates are stored in X:\WSUS\WsusContent...

Another thing you could do, and probably what I'd do is do a search for *.exe in that folder, then sort by file size. It's gonna be one of the larger ones. If you single click on the updates, your status bar in the explorer window gives you a brief description.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023,it's WSUS 10.0.You can use SSMS to log in the database, WID or external SQL Server would be both OK. Then query the [SUSDB].[dbo].[tbFile] table. For example Windows Vista SP2 is KB948465,you can execute the SQL:

```
select [FileDigest],[FileName] from [SUSDB].[dbo].[tbFile] where FileName like '%948465%';
```

The FileDigest is the filename that stores in the WsusContent.